# How to stop batch file running in background started using .vbs script

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, scheduled-tasks

I have a file invisible.vbs having following script

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
obj = WshShell.Run("e:\abc.bat", 0)
set WshShell = Nothing
```

`abc.bat` has following script

```
:loop
EVENTCREATE /T ERROR /L APPLICATION /ID 100 /D "This is  test message."
ping localhost -n 21 > nul
goto loop
```

Now I want to stop `abc.bat` manually but Question is HOW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into task manager and end the `cmd.exe` process.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: it depends. Do you want to stop it manually just this once? In that case go with the answer @BaliC already gave.

If you want to add an option to your script to allow for termination of the background loop, you're going to need something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12600633/1630171), and you need to spawn the background process via [`Exec()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f38xsxe%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), not via `Run()`. That way you can keep a handle that will allow you to terminate the process:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set p = sh.Exec("%COMSPEC% /c e:\abc.bat")

' IE dialog creation goes here

Do While p.Status = 0
  WScript.Sleep 100
  If ie.document.all("continue").Value = "no" Then p.Terminate
Loop
```

Answer (score 2):

To do it from a `.bat` file, first add this to `abc.bat`:

```
 TITLE=KILLME
```

Then run this command:

```
taskkill /fi "windowtitle eq KILLME"
```

You can set the title to anything you want. KILLME is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you have it open in command prompt you can press **CTRL** + **C**. Wait a few seconds and it will have terminated.